# Error updating mysql with apt-get (Debian)

Tags: mysql, debian, apt

I'm running a Debian 7 (wheezy) machine and I was doing my normal package updates with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and everything seemed to have updated alright except for mysql server. I got this as the output when I ran `apt-get upgrade`:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
mysql-server-5.5
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,092 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 24785 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-server-5.5 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 (using .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
[ ok ] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld already running.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It just looks like it wasn't able to stop the server, but I don't want to do anything rash since this is a production server. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Try the upgrade on a clone of your production environment first rather that trying to replace it "while its hot" - a process precisely designed to find issues like this before they become all nighters.  It'll be much better for your stress levels. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apt has told you that the initscript failed to `stop`. Most likely apt has installed the new code correctly and then tried to activate it by running

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

which the same thing as

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

You could try running this manually. The safest form is

```
# /usr/bin/service mysql restart
```

but first I would inspect

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/mysql.log
/var/log/mysql.err
```

There may be a simple cause for the error that you can fix, or a more severe error condition that you'll be glad to know about.